# upload youtube video without youtube api

Tags: asp.net, upload, youtube

How can we upload video to Youtube without using its api in asp.net?
My requirement is that user uploads video to our site and after admin approval that video is uploaded to Youtube. I'm using ASP.NET

Comment: I am very much interested in your project!! :)

Comment: They have an API for a reason - and from your description it is entirely unclear why you can't use it. Can you please expand on that?

Comment: I think youtube api produces a script for file upload control. if it isn't can you please tell me a sample code?

Comment: yes what is the reason for not using their API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jason I'm using this code:

```
  Dim request As YouTubeRequest
    Dim newVideo As New Video()

    newVideo.Title = "My Test Movie"
    newVideo.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema))
    newVideo.Keywords = "cars, funny"
    newVideo.Description = "My description"
    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = False
    newVideo.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema))

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = New GeoRssWhere(37, -122)

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = New MediaFileSource("c:\\flame.avi", "video/quicktime")
    Dim createdVideo As Video = request.Upload(newVideo)
```

But where to specify Youtube credentials and key?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at this? http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Direct_Upload

Authentication code can be found on the same page.
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Authentication

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim settings As YouTubeRequestSettings = New YouTubeRequestSettings("youtube", developerKey, username, password)

    Dim request As New YouTubeRequest(settings)
    Dim newVideo As New Video()

    newVideo.Title = "My Test Movie"
    newVideo.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema))
    newVideo.Keywords = "cars, funny"
    newVideo.Description = "My description"
    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = False
    newVideo.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema))

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = New GeoRssWhere(37, -122)

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = New MediaFileSource("c:\\drop.avi", "video/x-msvideo")
    Dim createdVideo As Video = request.Upload(newVideo)
```